# Saving MFC Paint Features

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to make a drawing board program with MFC and add the ability to save the picture, but it didn't work out so I'm asking you a question

```
struct Shape
{
    int type;  
    CPoint startP; 
    CPoint endP; 
    COLORREF color; 
    int penWidth; 
    int index;
    COLORREF m_defaultColor = RGB(0, 0, 0); 
    int m_defaultPenWidth = 1; 

    void SetColor(COLORREF newColor) {
        color = newColor;
    }

    void SetPenWidth(int newPenWidth) {
        penWidth = newPenWidth;
    }

};
```

Through this structure

```
std::vector<Shape> m_ellipes;
std::vector<Shape> m_line;
std::vector<Shape> m_dot;
```

Save each figure to that vector

```
void CPainterTest8Doc::SaveData(const std::string& filename)
{
    std::ofstream file(filename);
    for (const auto& shape : m_shapes) {
        file << shape.type << " "
            << shape.startP.x << " " << shape.startP.y << " "
            << shape.endP.x << " " << shape.endP.y << " "
            << GetRValue(shape.color) << " "
            << GetGValue(shape.color) << " "
            << GetBValue(shape.color) << " "
            << shape.penWidth << " "
            << shape.index << "\n";
    }
    file.close();
}

void CPainterTest8Doc::LoadData(const std::string& filename)
{
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    int r, g, b;
    Shape shape;
    m_shapes.clear();
    while (file >> shape.type
        >> shape.startP.x >> shape.startP.y
        >> shape.endP.x >> shape.endP.y
        >> r >> g >> b
        >> shape.penWidth
        >> shape.index) {
        shape.color = RGB(r, g, b);
        m_shapes.push_back(shape);
    }
    UpdateAllViews(NULL);
    file.close();
}
```

In this section, perform the save and import function

If you save it, all the figure information is saved as a text file in the vector, and when you import it, the figure in the text file needs to be redrawn, but even if you import it, the figure information does not come into the vector. May I know what the problem is?

Comment: If I were doing this, I'd start by creating *one* shape, writing it out, reading the data back into another shape object, then comparing them to see what parts are the same and what are different, to start figuring out where it's going wrong. (Though the usual with MFC is to use its built-in serialization instead of rolling it all on your own).

Comment: It's entirely unclear how those three `std::vector`s relate to the problem. Please show a [mcve]. Also, make sure to read [Serialization in MFC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/serialization-in-mfc), because that is what you're trying to reinvent.

Comment: Also to be flexibel I would write first the number of elements as a WORD (DWORD) followed by the elements themselves. I would not relay on EOF. This make you serialization more flexible. As written. Look at the MFCs built in object serialization.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get the results I wanted using built-in serialization.